# How to get google contacts but not gmail contacts?

Tags: android, contactscontract, google-contacts-api

I'm extracting the information of contacts stored in the phone. I'm working on 2.1.

I'm able to extract every RawContacts from the query including "auto gmail contacts" which I do not need.

I've done quite a bit searching on SO but could not find any good answers yet.

Looking at my phone's phonebook (HTC Hero), there's an option to hide those "auto gmail contacts" from the user. What I'm looking for is exactly that.

To clarify things, all I need is the google contacts but none of the gmail contacts.

In short, is there an implementation, may it be from the "where" clause or the Content-URI part where I can set to filter away the "auto gmail contacts"?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Google has two datasets for contacts. One is for the Gmail system, and the other is for Google Plus+.

The Gmail system is one database categorized by labels, for iOS sync the label associated with "My Contacts" in synchronized to the device.

I would assume this is the same for Android.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did a work around for it by extracting the contacts based on the accounts.